# Add child styles to Parent

Tags: css, styles, parent

Why does this css add padding to all the tables on a page instead of just the table with the set class:

CSS:

```
.tableclass th, tr, td {padding: 8px;}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tableclass>
<th>Header Text</th>
<tr>
<td>Content</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

I have 3 tables on the page, and they all have 8px padding--I just want the 8px padding in tableclass table. It's like I've set a global padding for all tables elements?!

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
.tableclass th, tr, td {padding: 8px;}
```

Is the same as this

```
.tableclass th {padding: 8px;}
tr {padding: 8px;}
td {padding: 8px;}
```

So, you're adding 8px padding to all `th`elements under `.tableclass` and then to all `tr` elements and all `td` elements.

As Rohit Azid suggested, here's how you should do it:

```
.tableclass tr,
.tableclass th,
.tableclass td {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

(Above I assume you want padding on the table-row element. If I assumed badly, I guess you know what to do)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if all the html tag are closed properly. Also you can try setting different css class to other two table

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to  **css** for this table as like this

```
.tableclass th, .tableclass tr td{
padding:8px;
}
```

Now if you want to padding than apply this class in your table as like this

```
<table class="tableclass">
<th>Header Text</th>
<tr>
<td>Content</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/DEYy6/